# Two Post requests, and not changing variables

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables, select

Okay so basically here is my page:
When the page loads, it sends an Ajax Post request to a my php file, and it sends two variables- ida=yes, and xquery=dropdown. That code is here:

```
function ddmenu() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var url = "dex.php";
var params = "xquery=dropdown&ida=yes";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("dropdown").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

This Ajax request activates this PHP, which is 100% correctly working.

```
$xquery = $_POST['xquery'];
// If $xquery is a dropdown.
if ($xquery = "dropdown") {
$dd = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$ddq = mysql_query($dd) or die('Error: '.mysql_error ());
echo 'Choose your Pokemon: <select id="tableid" onchange="tableloader()">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ddq)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['pokemon_name'].'">'.$row['natdex'].'-'.$row['pokemon_name'].'</option>';
}
echo "</select>".$xquery;
}
```

The select list generated here, uses the next function when it's value is changed. Another select list on the page also uses this function.

Now, I also have a second function that runs when a dropdown's value is changed. Now this function also sends an Ajax Post request, and the xquery and ida variables. My issue is that when I echo my xquery variable on my php page out, it still has xquery set as dropdown. When it should come out as tables. As the code basically says below:

```
function tableloader(str) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var url = "dex.php";
var var1 = document.getElementById("gendrop").value;
var var2 = document.getElementById("tableid").value;
var params = "xquery=tables&ida=yes&var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2;
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("searchdisplay").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Now this function, gets values from the drop down value generated in the first function, and also uses the drop down value from this dropdown:

```
<select id="gendrop" onchange="tableloader(this.value)">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="4">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
</select>
```

Now in the end, my question is why can I not get the values of my two dropdown menus, and why is it not changing my xquery variable and instead outputs the same thing to my php file even though it's a different ajaz request.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you may have conflicting variables. You should declare your `var xmlhttp` individually at the top of each function. See this previous post:

[How to stop XMLHTTP from clashing with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513263/how-to-stop-xmlhttp-from-clashing-with-each-other)

Comment: Also, jquery's library can make your life much easier when it comes to Ajax requests

Comment: I added a var xmlhttp to each of the two sections, and still it reproduces the same results. The thread you linked uses get requests instead of post. Which could be the potential difference.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after much hair pulling. Was one of those nit picky habits PHP has, I needed to == my if statement instead of just =. Thanks guys.